# Magento - saving custom column to order object

Tags: magento, customization, observers

I am making some amendments to an Magento eCommerce website - one of the options at the checkout page is for a user to select their organisation from a dropdown and save this 'organisation_id' to the Magento order object & the customer object.

Would this be best off using an observer or is there another way this should be achieved?

My Magento knowledge is limited so please feel free to point out anything obvious that I have missed out

Can anyone suggest any tips/code to get this started?

UPDATE... i found this on another Stackoverflow post

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

$setup->addAttribute('order', 'organisation_id', array(
'position'      => 1,
'input'         => 'text',
'type'          => 'varchar',
'label'         => 'Organisation ID',
'visible'       => 1,
'required'      => 0,
'user_defined' => 1,
'global'        => 1,
'visible_on_front'  => 1,
```

));

```
$installer->endSetup();
```

Would this create the database attributes for the organisation_id?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947179/how-to-add-product-specific-attribute-column-to-sales-flat-order-item-table

Comment: http://bhaumik25php.blogspot.in/2012/08/magento-adding-column-to.html

Comment: thanks Dushyant, I will check those links out

Comment: Take a look at this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/19298/146. I think it has everything you need. It adds a column to the quote and order tables and "caries" the value of the customer attribute all the way to the order object. It will even display it in the admin.